# Script to fetch file and delete in remote

Tags: shell, ssh, sftp

Currently i have a shell script which will sftp all the .txt files in the remote path to local and delete all the .txt files from the remote path.
But i need to change the logic such that i need to delete the file which successfully fetched from the remote path not all the file.
Current code:

```
sftp user@server << END_SCRIPT

cd /test
mget *.txt
rm *.txt 
quit

END_SCRIPT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two steps:

```
# get the files
sftp user@server << END_SCRIPT
cd /test
mget *.txt
quit
END_SCRIPT

# remove the files
{
  echo "cd /test"
  # assuming that all files in the current dir are fetched through sftp
  for file in *.txt; printf 'rm "%s"\n' "$file"; fi
  quit
} | sftp user@server
```

Comment: could you please explain me, how only the fetched files is stored in file?

Comment: Basically, you mget them into your directory, loop through the ones you got, and issue an `rm` from them.

Comment: The problem is, the current directory will have other files also apart from the files get from sftp.

Comment: In that case, create a new directory, get the files there, then run the rm loop, and move the files to wherever you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Another problem is once the i get the files to local, it will be moved immediately to another directory by a program. So i should get the name of the files while sftp the files itself.

Comment: I am able to get the file but while it tries to remove  got the below syntax error.

test.sh: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `printf'
test.sh: line 13: `  for file in *.trg; printf 'rm "%s"\n' "$file"; fi'